# LaTeX, polishing up tcolorbox with forest and tikz inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, forest, subfiles

I do not have much experience with graphics packages like tikz, however I decided to actually try and create something in LaTeX instead of for example GIMP.

I have this picture embedded in my LaTeX file:
[image]

But because some time later i might change some text in the picture I decided it would be probably better to change this in LaTeX instead of some external graphics editor so i tried reproducing the picture in LaTeX using forest package, tcolorbox package and tikz package.

This is what I have come up with:

[image]

I am creating this lets say picture as a subfile.

Here is the package definition from my main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  borderline north={2pt}{0pt}{cyan},
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  colback={gray},
  #1
}
```

And here is the subfile:

```
\documentclass[Main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{note}

\begin{center}
\color{white}Some text\\
\vspace*{0.2cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.9cm,height=0.3cm,keepaspectratio]{output-arrows.png}\\
\vspace*{0.2cm}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw [fill=cyan,draw=cyan, ultra thick] (0,0) circle (1.0cm)
            node  {Text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,0pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    align=center,
    parent anchor=west,
    child anchor=north
  }
  [, phantom, for children={fit=band}
    [
      [\color{white}Some text\\\color{white}and some other text
      ]
      [\color{white}Some text\\\color{white}text
      ]
      [\color{white}Some text\\\color{white}text
      ]
      [\color{white}Some text\\\color{white}some text\\\color{white}some text
      ]
      [\color{white}Some text\\\color{white}text
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{note}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I am not able to polish the result so it looks like the one above.

I need to correct the tree graph (no arrows and not centered with black line instead of white), then I would need to change the width of the box to the entire width of the page and also change the height so it looks similar to the one above.

When I am trying to polish it I unfortunately keep ending up with errors, can you please help me to achieve what I need? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know much about this subfiles thingy, but I could not make your file combination work. Anyway, even though I love forest, I'd choose a slightly different, Ti*k*Z "only" path to achieve the output. One can use `chains` in some interesting ways if one reads p. 604 of pgfmanual v3.1.5b, here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}
\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  borderline north={2pt}{0pt}{cyan},
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  colback={gray},
  #1
}
\begin{document}
\section*{\textcolor{blue!40!black}{Some text some text}}
\begin{note}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[text=white]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=leaves,
    start chain=A going {right=of \tikzchainprevious.south east},
    nodes={on chain,anchor=south,
    align=center,execute at end node={\global\let\mynumnodes\tikzchaincount}}]
  \node{Some text\\and some other text};
  \node{Some text\\text};
  \node{Some text\\text};
  \node{Some text\\some text\\some text};
  \node{Some text\\text};
\end{scope}
\foreach \X in {1,...,\mynumnodes}
 {\draw[line width=2pt,Triangle-,white] (A-\X|-leaves.north) -- ++ (0,2em) coordinate (t-\X);}
\draw[line cap=rect,line width=2pt,white] (t-1) -- (t-\mynumnodes)
    node[midway,above=2em,circle,fill=cyan!50,node font=\Large\bfseries,minimum size=9em] (c) 
    {Text}; 
\node[above=4em of c,node font=\large\bfseries](t){text};   
\path[line width=2pt,Triangle-,white,shorten >=2ex,shorten <=2ex]
 ([xshift=-1em]t.south) edge ([xshift=-1em]c.north) 
 ([xshift=1em]c.north) edge ([xshift=1em]t.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{note}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: In order to make extend the bounding box of the `tikzpicture` in the vertical direction, you may either add

```
\path (current bounding box.north) + (0,1); 
\path (current bounding box.south) + (0,-1);
```

or, equivalently,

```
\path (current bounding box.north) + (0,1)  (current bounding box.south) + (0,-1);
```

Full code and result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}
\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  borderline north={2pt}{0pt}{cyan},
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  colback={gray},
  #1
}
\begin{document}
\section*{\textcolor{blue!40!black}{Some text some text}}
\begin{note}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[text=white]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=leaves,
    start chain=A going {right=of \tikzchainprevious.south east},
    nodes={on chain,anchor=south,
    align=center,execute at end node={\global\let\mynumnodes\tikzchaincount}}]
  \node{Some text\\and some other text};
  \node{Some text\\text};
  \node{Some text\\text};
  \node{Some text\\some text\\some text};
  \node{Some text\\text};
\end{scope}
\foreach \X in {1,...,\mynumnodes}
 {\draw[line width=2pt,Triangle-,white] (A-\X|-leaves.north) -- ++ (0,2em) coordinate (t-\X);}
\draw[line cap=rect,line width=2pt,white] (t-1) -- (t-\mynumnodes)
    node[midway,above=2em,circle,fill=cyan!50,node font=\Large\bfseries,minimum size=9em] (c) 
    {Text}; 
\node[above=4em of c,node font=\large\bfseries](t){text};   
\path[line width=2pt,Triangle-,white,shorten >=2ex,shorten <=2ex]
 ([xshift=-1em]t.south) edge ([xshift=-1em]c.north) 
 ([xshift=1em]c.north) edge ([xshift=1em]t.south);
% enlarge bounding box in positive and negative y directions 
\path (current bounding box.north) + (0,1); 
\path (current bounding box.south) + (0,-1); 
% equivalent way of enlarging it
% \path (current bounding box.north) + (0,1)  (current bounding box.south) + (0,-1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{note}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment, it helped very much. I just slightly changed few things like the circle size, width of the tcolorbox and so on. I just wonder what is the best way to work with vspace inside tikz enviroment? \vspace does not work obviously, what is the common practice to simulate this? I was thinking about inserting blank node, but that is probably not the best solution. I am now trying to find this in the documentation, but had no success yet. Would you be so kind to provide some example in your answer above or point me in the right direction? Thank you very much

Comment: @Raymond_90 Yes, you can just at add a coordinate to make the bounding box larger. For instance, if you add `\path (current bounding box.north) + (0,2);` at the end, i.e. just before `\end{tikzpicture}`, you will add 2cm at the top.

Comment: Yes, thank you, how to achieve the same thing but with bottom? I would like to add 1 cm on top and 1 on bot and maybe change spacing between the elements by few px. The documentation seems confusing to me and I can not find it :-( When this is done I think it will be all, so far I am really happy with how this turned out. Thanks

Comment: @Raymond_90 Does `\path (current bounding box.north) + (0,1)  (current bounding box.south) + (0,-1);` give you the desired result?

Comment: Yes thank you, it does, I do not understand it though, tried exactly this `\path (current bounding box.south) + (0,-1);` and it did not work, but when combined it works? I am really confused, I suppose that I will have to thoroughly study the documentation, thank you very much. Do I understand correctly that I can use this approach to do similar thing \vspace does inside tikz enviroments? So in case I need to insert some vertical spece between say two nodes, I can use this? Overall thank you very much you helped me a lot, I would flag your answer as a solution if you post an answer

Comment: @Raymond_90 `\path (current bounding box.south) + (0,-1);` should work it it is at the very end of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: I did that, unfortunately after compiling multiple times it looked the same without any visible change. When I try just this `\path (current bounding box.north) + (0,1);` or this `\path (current bounding box.north) + (0,1) (current bounding box.south) + (0,-1);` it works perfectly.

Comment: @Raymond_90 I explicitly tested this, and on my machine it does work. I added an explicit code at the end of the answer.